# Как объединить 3 формы в одно email письмо

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmailer, html-form

Как объединить 3 формы с разных слайдов, чтобы данные с них уходили одним email сообщением?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сохраняете данные каждой формы (в сессию, в невидимые поля и т.д) и в конце используете их все.

Comment: Я бы сверстал всё одной большой формой с одной кнопкой submit внизу, стало быть с одной отправкой данных, а кнопки выше не отправляли бы форму, а лишь выводили на экран второй и третий фрагмент формы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё зависит от того, как у вас выстроены эти 3 формы.

Вариант 1: это 3 разные страницы(`page/register1,page/register2,...`)

**Самый простой способ:** сессия
Вариант посложнее - сервис через **DI**, примерно такой:

```php
class РегистрацияПокупки
{
    private FirstForm $firstStepData;
    private SecondForm $secondStepData;
    private ThirdForm $thirdStepData;

    private ResultDto $result;

    // formGetters
    // formGetters2
    // formGetters3
    // formSetters
    // formSetters2
    // formSetters3

    public function getData(){
        $data = $this->mapDataToDto();
        $this->flushForms();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Вариант 2: это всё одна страница, и всё меняется через JS
Ещё проще, ставим одинаковый `action` для всех форм, а дальше, уверен, с 3мя формами управитесь